# Download single file as pdf and multiple files as zip using axios in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

```
try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `${apilink}/download/`,
        {
          responseType: "blob",
          params: body,
        }
      );
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute("download", "file.zip");
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    } catch (e) {
      toaster.notify("Cannot Download.Please try again");
    }
```

I am currently using this method to download files coming from the API.
But here whether the file is single or multiple files they are being downloaded as Zip.

Is there any way i can change it so that if the single file is there it will be downloaded as it is and for multiple files they are downloaded as Zip file?

I am a beginner and not able to figure it out.

Comment: Could you please confirm the response(res.data) while a single file and multiple file? if possible please , update both responses in question

Comment: Blob {size: 19753, type: "text/html"}
size: 19753
type: "text/html"

wether multiple or single it is this

Comment: Before passing res.data to new Blob(res.data), May I know the response format . if there is single file or multiple file. if there is difference between them then we can handle conditionally